# Ensuring independence between streams of random numbers

Tags: java, random, random-seed

If I pick a seed (say 999) and generate a stream of random numbers, how can I choose a second seed that ensures the second stream of random numbers does not match the first? Does the second seed need to be measurably different from 999? Would something as simple as `seed2 = seed1 + 1000` work? The programming language I'm interested in is Java.

Comment: Maybe you want to be more specific what do you mean by "match" ?

Comment: Using `seed+1` is as safe a bet as any.

Comment: Statistically speaking, you're using a pseudorandom sequence, which is unique based on the initial seed value but is considered to have reasonably statistically random probability of selection; given a random seed, each subsequent element in the set of possible results is almost equally likely to be chosen, but given a known seed, the results are fixed. Because of this, we can typically assume that using two unique seeds will also be statistically unlikely to converge or align, since elements in each sequence have roughly the same probability as well.

Comment: In short, you should be able to get away with it, so long as the sequences don't converge (which is very unlikely).

Comment: What's wrong with `public Random()` constructor? I find it hard to believe that generating the seed manually would beat it.